# block network with Apache httpd 2.4

Tags: apache

Any idea how to block a network with Apache 2.4? This configuration does not block anything:

```
<Directory "/test">
    <RequireAll>
        Require not ip 10.52.80.0/24
        Require all granted
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```